# How to properly change the url slug, without affecting the navigation "back" in the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress store and I need different links for each variant.

I was able to get a plugin to create a slug for each variant.

But for each time the customer selects a variant, the url changes and if he hits "back" in the browser, he continues on the same page. Only the URL changes.

[image]
[image]

Would it be possible to correct this behavior with javascript?

I need to prevent the slug to have a history entry, is it possible?

See this link https://blazee.com.br/produto/calca-feminina-cintura-alta-folgada/?attribute_cor=Preto&attribute_tamanho=P

Comment: When you change the variant, the page doesn't reload. Only the url slug is changed, I just need it to behave as if it were on the same page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState might be useful

Comment: Thank you! Im changing some functions on the plugin, hope it works :D